# How to plot one point

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot one point on a graph. I put in `Plot[{3, 1}, {x, -2, 5}]`, but I get a line. How can I put in just one point?

Comment: `ListPlot[{{3, 1}}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 5},Automatic}]`

Comment: Take a look at `Graphics`, `Point` and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, one does't plot discrete points with `Plot`, which is mainly intended for more or less continuous functions. But it can be done.

```
Plot[{}, {x, -2, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {0, 1.5}},
  Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{3, 1}]}]
```

[image: plot]

However, `ListPlot` is the function provided for plotting point data. For your single point you could write it like this:

```
ListPlot[{{3, 1}}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {0, 1.5}}]
```

which gives the same plot as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

```
Show[Graphics[Point[{3, 1}]], PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-2, 5}}, 
 Axes -> Automatic]
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `Graphics[Point[{3, 1}], PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-2, 5}}, 
 Axes -> Automatic]`